# common lisp で while の使い方が解らない

Tags: common-lisp

lispの練習のため、AtCoderを始めましたが、`while`の使い方が良くわかりません。
rubyで言うところの下記の様なコードを書きたいのですが、どうしたら良いのでしょうか？

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby

divided = -1
odd = false

input = gets
input = gets
numbers = input.chomp.split(" ")
numbers = numbers.map { |x| x.to_i }

while (odd != true)
    numbers.each { |x|
        if x % 2 != 0 then
            odd = true
        end
    }
    numbers = numbers.map { |x| x / 2  }
    divied += 1
end

printf("%d\n", divided)
```

入力を数値のリストにするところまでは出来ていて、こんな感じです。

```lisp
 ; 引数をリストに変換
(defun split-by-space (string)
  (loop for i = 0 then (1+ j)
        as j = (position #\Space string :start i)
        collect (read-from-string (subseq string i j))
        while j))
(defun half (number) (/ number 2))
; 1行読み捨て
(read)
; n個の整数を読む
(defparameter args (read-line *standard-input* nil nil))
; n個の整数をリストに
(defparameter numbers (split-by-space args))
(defparameter divided 0)
;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`half` 関数ですが、除算(`/`)の結果が整数ではなく、rational 型になる場合があるので `floor` 関数を使います。

```lisp
* (type-of (/ 3 2))
RATIO
* (oddp (/ 3 2))
debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR @530D0FE4 in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1001348003}>:
  The value
    3/2
  is not of type
    INTEGER

* (oddp (floor 3 2))
T
```

[CLHS: Function READ, READ-PRESERVING-WHITESPACE](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/f_rd_rd.htm)

> **`read` parses the printed representation** of an object from input-stream and builds such an object.

なので、例えば stdin に `"1 2 3"` を入力すると、`(read)` は `1` を返します。1行読み捨ては、「n個の整数を読む」と同様に `read-line` を使うとよいかと思います。

```lisp
; 1行読み捨て
(read-line *standard-input* nil nil)
```

全体としては以下の様になります。

```lisp
(defun split-by-space (string)
  (loop for i = 0 then (1+ j)
        as j = (position #\Space string :start i)
        collect (read-from-string (subseq string i j))
        while j))
(defun half (number) (floor number 2))
; 1行読み捨て
(read-line *standard-input* nil nil)
; n個の整数を読む
(defparameter args (read-line *standard-input* nil nil))

;; n個の整数をリストに
(defparameter numbers (split-by-space args))
(format t "~d~%"
        (loop with nums = numbers
              for divided from 0
              thereis (and (member-if #'oddp nums) divided)
              do (setq nums (mapcar #'half nums))))
```